# Why can't I index by codistributed array size within an spmd block?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am trying to loop inside the codistributed pieces of a distributed array within a `spmd` block in MATLAB
R2020a:

```
input = rand([bignum,1],'distributed');
output = zeros([bignum,1],'distributed');
spmd
   for idx=1:numel(input)
       output(idx) = myFunction(input(idx));
   end
end
```

The above code gives me the following error:

```
Error detected on workers <all the work numbers>

Caused by:
    Error using codistributed/cast>iClass
    unsupported data type for conversion: 'codistributed'
```

If instead of looping over `idx=1:numel(input)` I loop over `idx=drange(1:numel(input))` my code works as expected, but this is not desired because `drange` assumes the default distribution scheme is being used for the array, when that isn't necessarily the case.  I'd rather have a snippet that works even if I build a distributed array out of smaller, not-necessarily-equally-size codstributed chunks.  Also, I have no idea how to index into an array with more than one dimension using `drange`

My understanding is that within an `spmd` block, any access to a distributed array actually corresponds to an access to one of the codistrubted pieces of said array.  So , for example, if `input` is a 100-element distrubted array split into 10 codistributed array within each worker, then `idx=1:numel(input)` should be equivalent to `idx=1:10` (because the worker-local codistriuted piece of `input` is 10 elements long) and `output(idx)=myFunction(input(idx))` should only be accessing the worker-local codistributed array member of `input` and `output`.

Why, then, doesn't the code example I have written work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the problem here isn't inside `myFunction`? The following code works correctly for me:

```
input = rand(10, 1, 'distributed');
output = zeros(10, 1, 'distributed');
spmd
    for idx = 1:numel(input)
        % if 'input' and 'output' have the same distribution scheme,
        % then no communication is required
        output(idx) = input(idx);
    end
end
assert(isequal(gather(input), gather(output)))
```

However, it's not terribly efficient. When accessing a `codistributed`, you are expected to do so "collectively" - i.e. all workers execute the same methods at the same time with the same input arguments. That's what's happening here, but in the case shown, only one worker has each element of `input` or `output`. In other words, all workers are executing each iteration of the loop, but performing no computation unless they are the worker that has the value.

You can even do random-access indexing in this way, but this is less efficient because each indexing call is a communication:

```
output2 = zeros(10, 1, 'distributed');
spmd
    n = numel(input);
    for idx = 1:n
        % the following line requires an element of 'input'
        % to be sent to the worker which has the corresponding
        % element of 'output'.
        output2(n - idx + 1) = input(idx);
    end
end
assert(isequal(gather(input), flip(gather(output2))))
```

I would strongly recommend that if you want to work with `codistributed` inside `spmd`, you extract the local part from the `codistributed` array, work with that locally (possibly with communication if needed), and then put things back together.

Comment: "In other words, all workers are executing each iteration of the loop, but performing no computation unless they are the worker that has the value."  Shouldn't `1:numel(input)` return only the size of the codistributed array from input that belongs to each individual worker?  Why would every worker iterate over the entire array?

Comment: No, that's not how `codistributed` works. `numel` on a `codistributed` tells you the number of elements of the whole array. If you want to work on only the local part, extract the local part using `getLocalPart`, and work with that.

Comment: Will `getLocalPart` create a copy of the codistributed portion of `input`?  Also, done this way do I have to somehow use `codistributed.build` to make `output`? How do I do that without extraneous copying?

Comment: `getLocalPart` will take advantage of MATLAB's normal "copy-on-write" behaviour - so a copy is taken only when you modify it. As usual in MATLAB, it can be a bit tricky to avoid making a copy if the original `codistributed` array is still accessible somewhere. Again, `codistributed.build` will use "copy-on-write", so that should not cause an extra memory allocation.